# Not Working Jquery Enter Key and Shift-Enter key

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

My J-Query key press,shift-key is not working in Mozilla Firefox need help thanks in advance.

J-Query using : jquery-1.7.2.min.js

```
<html><body>
<textarea id = 'text' rows='4' cols='50' style = 'width: 50%;height:15%;' placeholder = 'Enter Post....'></textarea>
</body></html>

<script>

$('#text').keypress(
    function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey) {
            alert("a");
        }
        else if(e.keyCode == 13){
            alert("sdf");
        }
    }
);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your code in a document ready handler -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#text').keypress(function (e) {   
       if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey) {
           console.log("a");
       } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
           console.log("sdf");
       }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#text').keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey) {
         alert("shift plus enter");
         }
});
```

Comment: my bad ... updated the code  .Could you please check ?